# Python3 matplotlib multi layer x-labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and want some help to display multi layer x-labels.

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    "midterm": {"anna": [2,8,6], "adams": [5,10,8], "jane":[4,10,8]},
    "final": {"anna": [3,7,5], "adams": [6,8,7], "jane":[2,8,7]}
}


for key in data.keys():
    y = data[key]["anna"] + data[key]["adams"]+data[key]["jane"]
    plt.plot(y, label=key)

x_location = [1,4,7]
x_labels = ["anna", "adams", "jane"]
plt.xticks(x_location, x_labels)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It outputs the following plot:
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBwkm.png)

I want the x-label to be multi layer such as:
[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IRdN.png)

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the code below. Hope this helps...

Little explanation...

1. Get the data in a format that is easy to plot. Basically, the indexing has to be such that level 0 is the names (so that would be the lowest level in the x-axis), then the subject (Math, Eng,...). Would suggest you do a print of df to see how it looks
2. Plot using pandas, which will give you the plot you need.
3. For the inner (upper) set of xticklabels, you need the subjects, which is in the level 1 index. Note that in case of lineplot, matplotlib gives extra space on left and right (whitespace) and to enable you to use `set_xticklabels()`, you need to add blanks at the start and end of the array, which is what I have done
4. Next, draw the vertical lines which would be occur each time the subjects values are complete... Add -0.5 so that the lines are between the ticks and you have the positions of each of the separator lines. `vlines` will help you draw these. Note that here, I have skipped the first and last vertical lines as I didn't see it in your expected pic
5. Finally, add the text halfway between the positions and did a little change of size and bold to differentiate the first and second levels of xticklabels.

Some of the parts have been borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048752/adding-multi-level-x-axis-to-matplotlib-seaborn-month-and-year)

```
## Starting with your data...
data = {"midterm": {"anna": [2,8,6], "adams": [5,10,8], "jane":[4,10,8]}, "final": {"anna": [3,7,5], "adams": [6,8,7], "jane":[2,8,7]}}

## Convert to the form that is easy to plot - First index by name and then by Subject
df=pd.DataFrame(data).drop('final', axis=1).explode('midterm')
df['final']=pd.DataFrame(data).drop('midterm', axis=1).explode('final')
df['Subject'] = ['Math', 'Eng', 'Hist']*3
df.set_index('Subject', append=True, inplace=True)

## Figure of size you want and plot... 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
df.plot(xlabel='', ax=ax)

## Set the x-tick labels to the subjects (first level). As lineplot gives extra space at start and end, add blanks
myticklabels= df.index.get_level_values(level=1).tolist()
myticklabels.insert(0,'') 
myticklabels.append('')

## First level labels as per subject 
ax.set_xticklabels(myticklabels, rotation=0)

## Draw vertical lines (I am not including the lines at the ends)
pos=[]
pos.append(-0.5)
for i in range(len(df.index.unique(level=0))):
    pos.append((i+1)*len(df.index.unique(level='Subject'))-0.5)
ax.vlines(pos[1:-1], 0, -0.4, color='black', lw=1.5, clip_on=False, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())

## Draw second level axes ticklables
for ps0, ps1, lbl in zip(pos[:-1], pos[1:], df.index.unique(level=0)):
    ax.text((ps0 + ps1) / 2, -0.12, lbl, ha='center', clip_on=False, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), weight = 'bold', size=13)
```

**Plot**

[image]