# Create adjacent subplots using barh in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am wanting to recreate [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JmHs.jpg) using matplotlib and I am struggling to et the ratios correct with regards to the white space between the bars in the first subplot. Could anyone please offer some advice?

Much appreciated!

I have tried this so far, but [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2S9X.png) isn't quite right. I am also struggling with the legend not having all of the labels I have stated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#This style looks the best
plt.style.use('default')

#Sizes the plot nicely to see in python
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

labels_alcohol = ['Borchers et al.', 'Donnelly et al.']
values_alcohol = [24, 1]

labels_formalin = ['Wang and Feng', 'van Haaren et al.', 'Borchers et al.', 'Gustafson et al.', 'Ebacher et al.']
values_formalin = [3, 3, 24, 52, 52]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
# Remove vertical space between axes
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

# Plot each graph, and manually set the y tick values
axs[0].barh(labels_alcohol[0], values_alcohol[0], color='white', label='No Change', hatch="\\", edgecolor="black", height=0.2)
axs[0].barh(labels_alcohol[1], values_alcohol[1], color='white', label='Major Change', hatch="x", edgecolor="black", height=0.2)
axs[0].set_ylabel('Alcohol')

axs[1].barh(labels_formalin[0], values_formalin[0], color='white', label='_No Change', hatch="\\", edgecolor="black", height=0.8)
axs[1].barh(labels_formalin[1], values_formalin[1], color='white', label='_Major Change', hatch="x", edgecolor="black", height=0.8)
axs[1].barh(labels_formalin[2], values_formalin[2], color='white', label='Minor Change', hatch="o", edgecolor="black", height=0.8)
axs[1].barh(labels_formalin[3], values_formalin[3], color='white', label='_No Change', hatch="\\", edgecolor="black", height=0.8)
axs[1].barh(labels_formalin[4], values_formalin[4], color='white', label='_No Change', hatch="\\", edgecolor="black", height=0.8)
axs[1].set_ylabel('Formalin')

plt.xlabel('Weeks Stored')
plt.legend()

plt.savefig("Storage Protocol Plot.pdf")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of working with subplots, one could draw everything into one plot, and then add extra labels and lines. See e.g. [Adding multi level X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048752/adding-multi-level-x-axis), but with `ax.get_yaxis_transform()` instead of `ax.get_xaxis_transform()`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, it worked a treat! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to an idea from JohanC (See comment below original post) I managed to come up with a solution. I made it one plot and simply added a horizontal line using `plt.axhline` which divided the plot into the two categories. I just added two text blocks for the titles of the categories using `plt.text`.

Here are the examples of the additions I made:

`plt.axhline(y = 1.5, xmin=-0.15, xmax=1.05, color = 'black', linewidth=0.8, linestyle = '-', clip_on=False)`

`plt.text(x=55.5, y=0, s='Alcohol', rotation='vertical', clip_on=False, fontsize='x-large')`